# Can not start Mongodb 2.6.3 on Windows as service

Tags: windows, mongodb

Trying to install and start mongodb service on widnows 7 x64

mongod.cfg:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "c:\\mongo\\logs\\mongo.log"
   quiet: true
   logAppend: true

storage:
   dbPath: "C:\\mongo\\data"
   directoryPerDB: true
```

This works fine (mongodb starts, wrhites to logs/mongo.log):

```
bin\mongod.exe --config mongod.cfg
```

I install service:
bin\mongod.exe --config mongod.cfg --install

But on service start I've got an alert:

> Windows could not start the MongoDB service on Local Computer.
>
> ```
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
> ```

nothing in log file

tried config in plain format:

```
logpath=c:\mongo\logs\mongo.log
logappend=true 
dbpath=C:\mongo\data
directoryperdb=true
```

the same result

Comment: Which user are you using for the service?

Comment: Standard: Local system account. It all worked with mongodb 2.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use the full path of the configuration file when you install the windows service, for example:

```
bin\mongod.exe --config c:\mongo\mongod.cfg --install
```

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully to use the manual creation method with "sc.exe create ..." and although that created the service, trying to start it gave me this 1053 error.