# enabling mongoDB windows service

Tags: windows, mongodb, database

I want to enable mongoDB service in my windows server.these are codes I use and the output of them ,but didn't work.
(I run them in powershell as admin)

```
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin> .\mongod.exe --remove
2014-08-07T14:10:16.555+0430 Trying to remove Windows service 'MongoDB'
2014-08-07T14:10:16.557+0430 Could not find a service named 'MongoDB' to remove
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin> .\mongod.exe --install --dbpath c:\db --logpath c:\db\logs
PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin> .\mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test

2014-08-07T14:11:02.640+0430 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2014-08-07T14:11:02.644+0430 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at
 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146`

exception: connect failed
```

And in log file I have this :

`2014-08-07T14:13:06.848+0430 --install has to be used with --logpath`

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to create a config file and install with `--config`. This is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb)

Comment: I try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577569/can-not-start-mongodb-2-6-3-on-windows-as-service?rq=1

Comment: After creating the service, did you start it with `net start MongoDB` (or via the Services control panel)? If the service fails to start, have a look in the log file for a relevant error message (you have the logpath set to `c:\db\logs`).

Comment: `The service name is invalid.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.              `I use `--serviceName mongo` to specify a name.but when I type `net start mongo` this error happend.